# Livewire - wire:click messing up when I call it multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

So I am trying to create this quiz app in Laravel+Livewire.

I have this list-group of answers in HTML and whenever I click on an answer, I want it to save it as 'selected' in my array, so when the user submits the answer, I can directly save it in the database.

When I click submit ('Trimite raspunsul' in my language), I print the array of 'selectat' (which basically has a value of 0/1 based on if the users selected that answer or not) so I can verify it works correctly.

I click the answers and then 'submit': it shows that the selected answers are stored correctly: all indexes from 0-4 have value of 1.

The problem comes when I deselect all the answers: the value of the array starts messing up as you can see in this GIF:

Link to the GIF if you're unable to see it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/liiGF.gif

I mention that I also have a local javascript function to set the list-item to active when it's clicked upon so I don't have to wait for livewire to load it.

Here's my component code:

```php
public $selectat = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

public function selectatRaspuns($id) {
    if($this->selectat[$id] == 0) {
        $this->selectat[$id] = 1;
    }
    else {
        $this->selectat[$id] = 0;
    }
    /*
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('selectatRaspuns', [
        ['idbuton' => $id],
    ]); */
}

public function submitRaspunsuri() {
    dd($this->selectat);
}
```

and here is my blade:

```html
<div class="list-group" wire:ignore>
    @for ($i = 0; $i < $question->noA; $i++)
    <button type="button" id="buton{{ $i }}" wire:click.prevent="selectatRaspuns({{$i}})" 
    @if($selectat[$i] == 1)    
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active"
    @else  
    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
    @endif    
        >
        <b>{{ $litere[$i] }}.</b> 
        {{ $question->answer($i) }}
    </button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("buton"+@js($i)).addEventListener("click", function() {
            ButonClicked(@js($i));
        });
    </script>
        
    @endfor
</div>

<!-- and here's my Submit Answers button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" wire:click="submitRaspunsuri()">                           
        <span>Trimite raspunsul</span>
</button>
```

What can I do to make the variables in the array to update correctly? Thanks a lot guys :)